# SQL selection query that discards rows that share some value with another row

Tags: sql, oracle

Suppose I have the next SQL table, with these sample values:

```
ID    Date        User     Publish
----------------------------------
1     05/20/16    Peter    1
2     05/20/16    Peter    2      <= Discarded
3     05/20/16    John     2
4     05/28/16    John     1
5     05/28/16    John     2      <= Discarded
6     07/01/16    Peter    2
7     07/01/16    John     2
```

What I want to get is a query to select all rows but in case there are two rows for the same date and user, retrieve the one with 'Publish' value to '1', so in the example I get the rows 1, 3, 4, 6 and 7.

I resolve the problem programmatically but I wonder if exists a way to solve it with a proper sql query.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will discard all but the first row (ordered by `publish`) for each group of `date` and `user`:

```
SELECT ID, "Date", User, Publish
FROM   (
  SELECT t.*,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY "Date", User ORDER BY Publish ) AS rn
  FROM   table_name t
)
WHERE rn = 1;
```

Comment: I didn't realize when making the example for the question that "date" and user were reserved words. Anyway the answer is correct. Thanks!